# Creating HTML Nav from a database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, navigationbar

I am currently redesigning my website to use PHP and databases (opposed to Bootstrap, CSS, and HTML) and I am currently having issues grabbing my links from my database and putting them in my nav menu. I prefer to use a database to prevent the need of re-entering all the links if I eventually decide to change them. The issue is I can't seem to get any HTML output here, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am fairly new to PHP so there may be something trivial that I just haven't grasped the concept of but currently this code only displays the bullet point of the `<ul>` on the page. My database and code are below. The database is confirmed able to connect.

[image]

test.php:

```
require_once('config.php');
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT link_title, link_url FROM links ORDER BY link_id";

if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">';
    foreach($result as $link) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo "<a href='{$link->link_url}'>{$link->link_title}</a>\n";
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$conn->close();
```

Comment: `$result` is a mysqli result object. you can NOT `foreach` it. it's not an array. it should be more like `while($link = $result->fetchRow()) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

  echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">';
  while($link = $result->fetch_object()) {
       echo '<li>';
       echo "<a href='{$link->link_url}'>{$link->link_title}</a>\n";
       echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';

/* free result set */
$result->free(); // there is no method "close" for result -> http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php
}
```